# GalIC-compilation and usage

Tags: make, mpi

Can anyone help me with GalIC code - compilation and usage, please. 
Downloaded from
https://www.h-its.org/tap-software-en/galic-code/

In the README file, there are a list of non-standard libraries for compilation:
mpi - I downloaded using:

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc gsl
sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl hdf5
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

I prepared files for compilation as described in the readme file. But I am getting errors:

```
$ make
cc          -Ibuild -c src/main.c -o build/main.o
src/main.c:8:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory

 #include <mpi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, headers and libraries necessary for building software from source are usually provided by separate *development packages*: in this case, you probably need `libmpich-dev`, `libgsl-dev`, and `libhdf5-dev`

Comment: Thank you, for a response to the question. These packages I installed, even though the code is not possible to compile.